My phone talk by Android auto even without a car and android auto uninstalled, help!
I have a blackberry key2 with android 8.1.0. I often rent cars with android auto, so I connect my phone to different cars. It's a month that randomly my mobile phone starts to say louder "Sorry, I didn't understand". It happens at home, in the office, during the night.
I checked on Google activity and it says that it's activated by android auto. So I removed android auto app from the phone, and the problem continues.
How is it possible?
How can android auto app activate the phone, even if android auto app is not in the phone?
I don't talk to the phone, I don't touch the phone, but it happens randomly.
This is the screenshot of the activity:

